# 2d Array sorting by lowest to highest number

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I would like to sort this 2D array so it would output something  like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and also tell me how many moves it made to rearange. Thank you allot !

Here is my code so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        int firstArray [][] ={{3,8,5},{1,6,9},{2,4,7}};

        System.out.println("This is array to sort:");
        displayArray(firstArray);
    }

    public static void  displayArray(int x[][])    {
       for (int row=0;row<x.length;row++) {
         for(int column = 0;column<x[row].length; column++) {
               System.out.print(x[row][column]+"\t");
         }
         System.out.println();
       }
    }
```

Comment: This code would only print the array. Give us a code that you have tried or facing a problem with.

Comment: This can be done in two `for-loops` now think!

Comment: Mister Tdorno
Can you please help me out this is for my home assigment and the teacher only taught us basics. I have been reading lots and cant figure. Please i would be really greatfull!

Answer (score 3):

First you take every single number out of the array, and then you do a simple sort to figure out the order in which to print the numbers. You should look up the `compare`method in Java or make your own if you need to.

When you got that add an integer that counts every operation you do and increment it by 1 every time you do an operation. Then print it when you are done.

Comment: But I dont know how to sort numbers?

Comment: @user2414434: there are several ways to sort. You should first look up sorting algorithms, probably *before* posting code and a question here. We're not here to write your code for you but to answer specific questions. So please read up on sorting, and then come back with questions.

Comment: I'll update my explanation.

Comment: +1 for giving a good solution without giving teh codez

Answer (score 2):

Thats not simply sorting.

You could solve thsi without too much hassle by first building a flat 1D array with all the elements of the nested array. Then sort that (using Arrays.sort() for example) and finally copy back the sorted data with a nested loop (the code you have in displayarray could be modified to perform the copies).

An alternate way to sort such messes *in place* would be to create a wrapper class that implements java.util.List that maps by index into the 2D array. You could then use Collections.sort() to sort it directly.

As for counting how many moves to sort, thats totally the problem of the sorting method. If you want to know, instrument the sorting code to count that (either your own, or premade code copied from someone else, e.g. the JRE source).

Answer (score 0):

this code will sort the column i don't know if that helps you

```
class some{
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
    int firstArray [][] ={{3,8,5},{1,6,9},{2,4,7}};

    System.out.println("This is array to sort:");
    displayArray(firstArray);
    firstArray = Sort(firstArray);
    System.out.println();
    displayArray(firstArray);

}


public static void  displayArray(int x[][])    {
   for (int row=0;row<x.length;row++) {
     for(int column = 0;column<x[row].length; column++) {
           System.out.print(x[row][column]+"\t");
     }
     System.out.println();
   }
}
public static int[][]  Sort(int x[][])    {
  int tmp = 0;
   for (int row=0;row<x.length;row++) {
     for(int column = 0;column<x[row].length; column++) {
           for (int i =column+1;i<x[row].length ;i++ ) {
            if(x[row][column]>x[row][i]){
            tmp= x[row][column];
            x[row][column] = x[row][i];
            x[row][i] = tmp ;
          }//end of if
           }
     }
     System.out.println();

   }
   return x ;
}//end of method sort
```

}

Comment: thank you very much. May life treats you well. You are a really good man. Helped me allot!